# How did the Earth cool from a temperature of hundreds-of-degrees, if runaway greenhouse effects also happen?

Tags: atmosphere, climate, temperature

From [this](https://futurism.com/the-byte/scientists-simulated-runaway-greenhouse-effect) article:

> the team from the University of Geneva (UNIGE) and the French National Centre for Scientific Research (CNRS) studied what would happen if the greenhouse effect were trapped inside the Earth's atmosphere as if under an emergency thermal blanket.
>
> If the effect were to rise too much, the amount of water vapor from evaporating oceans could be lethal.
>
> "There is a critical threshold for this amount of water vapor, beyond which the planet cannot cool down anymore," said main author and UNIGE postdoctoral researcher Guillaume Chaverot in the statement. "From there, everything gets carried away until the oceans end up getting fully evaporated and the temperature reaches several hundred degrees."

The Earth was hotter than this in the past, so water vapour in the atmosphere would have been an effect in place then, right?

How did the Earth previously cool down from these levels?

Comment: Good question. The answer likely involves the Sun being less hot by that time, and Earth getting water and its current atmosphere (from comets or from volcanoes) after having cooled a lot.